# Let axvline end at certain y-value

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I was plotting a histogram with pandas and pyplot. For additional information, I added lines at certain percentiles of the histogram distribution. I already found out that you can make a `axvline` appear with a certain % height of the whole chart:

```
cycle_df = pd.DataFrame(results)
plot = cycle_df.plot.hist(bins=30, label='Cycle time')

plot.axvline(np.percentile(cycle_df,5), label='5%', color='red', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=2, ymax=0.25)
plot.axvline(np.percentile(cycle_df,95), label='95%', color='blue', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=2, ymax=0.25)
```

Is it possible to let the red/blue lines end exactly where the histogram bar ends too to look smooth?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's definitely possible but I'm not sure if it's easy to do with `pandas.DataFrame.hist` because that doesn't return the histogram data. You would have to do another `matplotlib.pyplot.hist` (or `numpy.hist`) to get the actual bins and heights.

However if you use `matplotlib` directly this would work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use('ggplot')

import numpy as np

data = np.random.normal(550, 20, 100000)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
plot = ax.hist(data, bins=30, label='Cycle time', color='darkgrey')

ps = np.percentile(data, [5, 95])
_, ymax = ax.get_ybound()

# Search for the heights of the bins in which the percentiles are
heights = plot[0][np.searchsorted(plot[1], ps, side='left')-1]

# The height should be the bin-height divided by the y_bound (at least if y_min is zero)
ax.axvline(ps[0], label='5%', color='red', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=2, ymax=heights[0] / ymax)
ax.axvline(ps[1], label='95%', color='blue', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=2, ymax=heights[1] / ymax)
plt.legend()
```

[image]

In case you don't want to bother with calculating the relative height, you could also use `Lines2D` from `matplotlib.lines`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.lines as mlines

plt.style.use('ggplot')

import numpy as np

data = np.random.normal(550, 20, 100000)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
plot = ax.hist(data, bins=30, label='Cycle time', color='darkgrey')

ps = np.percentile(data, [5, 95])

# Search for the heights of the bins in which the percentiles are
heights = plot[0][np.searchsorted(plot[1], ps, side='left')-1]

# The height should be the bin-height divided by the y_bound (at least if y_min is zero)
l1 = mlines.Line2D([ps[0], ps[0]], [0, heights[0]], label='5%', color='red', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=2)
l2 = mlines.Line2D([ps[1], ps[1]], [0, heights[1]], label='95%', color='blue', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=2)
ax.add_line(l1)
ax.add_line(l2)
plt.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I used the second option and it worked perfectly how intended it to do.